# How to show Strings from array in UITableView?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, uitableview

I have an array like this:

```
var converter1 = [
        ["title": "value1", "kf": "1"],
        ["title": "value2", "kf": "4.324"]]
```

And `if`, `else` case in `cellForRowAt`:

```
let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell") as! resultTableViewCell


            cell1.nameResult.text = converter1[indexPath.row]
            cell1.labelResult.text = converter1[indexPath.row]


            return cell1
```

How could I in `nameResult.text` show "title" and "kf" in `labelResult`?

Comment: Do you want to display the keys ("title" and "kf") or the values ("value1" and "1")?

Comment: @vadian “title” and “kf” - type names. I want to show it’s values like “value1” is “1”

Comment: cell1.nameResult.text = converter1[indexPath.row]["title"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary seems to contain a "title" key/value pair and a "kf" key/value pair. I'm not completely clear on what you want to do, but you might try something like this:

```
let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell") as! resultTableViewCell

cell1.nameResult.text = converter1[indexPath.row]["title"]
cell1.labelResult.text = converter1[indexPath.row]["kf"]

return cell1
```

Comment: Take a look at vadian's suggestion of creating a struct to model your data. That's a better way to go than using a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the values with key subscription

```
let item = converter1[indexPath.row]
cell1.nameResult.text = item["title"]
cell1.labelResult.text = item["kf"]
```

---

A much better solution is a custom struct

```
struct Converter {
   let title, kf : String 
}

let converter1 = [
    Converter(title: "value1", kf: "1"),
    Converter(title: "value2", kf: "4.324")]
```

...

```
let item = converter1[indexPath.row]
cell1.nameResult.text = item.title
cell1.labelResult.text = item.kf
```

Comment: Beat you to it, by at least 10 seconds!  

Comment: I like your edit to suggest a custom struct. (voted.) That's much safer and clearer than a generic dictionary. And if the source data is JSON, it's trivial to use the new JSONDecoder to create a custom struct directly from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I good way to deal with this kind of problem is to use a playground and let type inference tell you what data types you're dealing with.  Here's an example of taking your structure apart.

```
let converter1 = [
    ["title": "value1", "kf": "1"],
    ["title": "value2", "kf": "4.324"]]
let val0 = converter1[0]
if let strTitle = val0["title"],
    let strKf = val0["kf"] {
    print("\(strTitle) : \(strKf)")
}
```